# Can I return a different resource when user request a url in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Let's take an example.
Such as I type the url http://www.google.com in Chrome, but I wish the extension get the response from http://www.bing.com actually, and show the content on the web page. The url on the address bar still is google. (Not a redirect.)
So for the user, he thinks the page is got from google.

Is it possible?

Comment: You're not trying to go phishing, are you?

Comment: No, My clients want to replace the Youtube's video ad with his Ad. I did something research, especially on Adblock. But finally, the solution I can get is that one.   It's really like a phishing. Do you have any idea about it?